# How to get the not similar data from a access data base using VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I want to extract data from a access database but just not all data if it's similar example if the db contains (a,b,b,b,c) I want to get only (a,b,c).

Hope it's clear enough!

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & folderPath & "\" & gp

       Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Open "SELECT GaCodeMun FROM ModificationsAttributsParcours WHERE GaCodeMun <> '' ", cn, , , adCmdText

TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: How about using DISTINCT?

Comment: Distinct in the sql sentence you mean?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT GaCodeMun` instead of `SELECT GaCodeMun`

Comment: @Rene you should post comments that fully answer the questions as an answer. That way we can see the question is answered, and you can get rep for it. It seems like that fully answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT to retrieve unique values.
Your SELECT statement would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GaCodeMun FROM ModificationsAttributsParcours WHERE GaCodeMun <> ''
```

If you want to calculate the total of distinct values, you can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(GaCodeMun) AS Total
from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT GaCodeMun 
    FROM ModificationsAttributsParcours
    WHERE GaCodeMun <> ''
)
```

If you want to wrap it up in one query, you can use below query. Total of distinct values however will be reflected per each unique value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GaCodeMun, 
(
SELECT COUNT(GaCodeMun) AS Total
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT GaCodeMun
    FROM ModificationsAttributsParcours
    WHERE GaCodeMun <> ''
    )
)
FROM ModificationsAttributsParcours
```

Comment: By any chance did you know how I can get the numbers of DISCTINCT data also?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to get the number of times an unique value appears? Like per your example a-> 1, b-> 3, c -> 1?

Comment: Kind of but the total of it:  a,b,b,b,c = 3 (total of distinct) Sorry if i wasn't clear, it's not my first language.

Comment: I've adjusted my previous answer.